How load image like input tensor in C?
I'm developing an inference application in C using TensorFlow. In this context, I've written code to capture the first and last layers of the model, and as an example, I've created a hypothetical matrix to validate the application.
Here's an example of simple data with dimensions of batch_size, height, width, and channels:
// Specify input tensor dimensions
    int ndims = 4; // Number of dimensions of the input tensor
    int64_t dims[] = {1, 224, 224, 3}; // Dimensions of the input tensor (batch_size x height x width x channels)

 // Generate sample data for input tensor
    float data[1 * 224 * 224 * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 * 224 * 224 * 3); i++) {
        data[i] = 1.00;
    }
    int ndata = sizeof(float) * 1 * 224 * 224 * 3;

Now, I want to load an image, obtaining the necessary values such as pixels and dimension values. For this purpose, I've developed this part using the stb_image library.
    // Load image
    const char* filename = "image.png"; 
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char *img = stbi_load(filename, &width, &height, &channels, 0); 
    if (img == NULL) {
        printf("Error in loading the image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Specify input tensor dimensions
    int ndims = 4; // Number of dimensions of the input tensor
    int64_t dims[] = {1, 224, 224, 3}; // Dimensions of the input tensor (batch_size x height x width x channels)

    // Aloca dinamicamente memória para armazenar os valores dos pixels da imagem
    float *data = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * height * width * channels);
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Error in allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populates the 'data' array with the values of the image's pixels
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < channels; c++) {
                data[(y * width + x) * channels + c] = img[(y * width + x) * channels + c] / 255.0f; // Normaliza os valores dos pixels para o intervalo [0, 1]
            }
        }
    }
    int ndata = sizeof(float) * 1 * 224 * 224 * 3;

    // Create input tensor
    TF_Tensor* input_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, ndims, data, ndata, &NoOpDeallocator, 0);
    if (input_tensor != NULL) {
        printf("TF_NewTensor is OK\n");
    } else {
        printf("ERROR: Failed TF_NewTensor\n");
    }

EDIT
The dynamically allocated memory for storing pixel values as floats is being freed immediately after its allocation. This means that the data pointer is being freed before it's used to create the input tensor. This may cause issues as the tensor's data pointer needs to remain valid throughout its usage.
There's a slight difference in the way the input tensor is created:
In the original code (TF_NewTensor), the data pointer (data) is directly passed to the tensor constructor.
In the edited code (TF_AllocateTensor), the tensor is allocated with TF_AllocateTensor, but it seems the data pointer is not assigned to it. This means that the tensor is allocated but not initialized with the image data. Therefore, it might not contain the expected data when used later in the program.
// Allocate data for inputs & outputs
    TF_Tensor** InputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * NumInputs);
    TF_Tensor** OutputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*) * NumOutputs);

    // Specify input tensor dimensions
    int ndims = 4; // Number of dimensions of the input tensor
    int64_t dims[] = {1, 224, 224, 3}; // Dimensions of the input tensor (batch_size x height x width x channels)

    // Load the image using stb_image.h
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char *image_data = stbi_load("play_accept_call1.png", &width, &height, &channels, 0);

    // Check if the image was loaded successfully
    if (!image_data) {
        printf("Error loading the image.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Allocate memory to store pixel values as float
    float *data = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * dims[1] * dims[2] * dims[3]);

    // Convert pixel values from unsigned char to float and normalize to the range [0, 1]
    for (int i = 0; i < dims[1] * dims[2] * dims[3]; i++) {
        data[i] = (float)image_data[i] / 255.0;
    }

    // Free the memory allocated for the image data
    stbi_image_free(image_data);

    // Use the image data as needed

    // Free the memory allocated for the float array
    free(data);

    // Calculate the total size of the data
    int ndata = sizeof(float) * 1 * 224 * 224 * 3;

    // Create input tensor
    TF_Tensor* input_tensor = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, ndims, ndata);

However, when running the inference, I'm getting unexpected softmax outputs. The probabilities do not correspond to reality. The model was built in Python and has already been validated with an accuracy of 97%. Therefore, I'm using the weights from this model.
Does it make sense to load the image this way? I'm not familiar with the method of loading and capturing image values in C.
Despite the new change, the prediction outputs still do not match the tested images. Could someone tell me to point out the inconsistency in loading the image?

The preferred way of allocating your tensor would be a call to TF_AllocateTensor() instead of TF_NewTensor(), then using TF_TensorData() to obtain data pointer and write to it (e.g., data = (float*)TF_TensorData(input_tensor). But I didn't see anything wrong with your way of doing it.

For the TF_NewTensor() function, how should I set the parameters when working with images (detections)? For example, should I pass a 2x2 matrix containing the pixels in the data parameter? And are ndims and dims indeed as I commented: "// Number of dimensions of the input tensor" and "// Dimensions of the input tensor (batch_size x height x width x channels)"?

Your ndims looks good, NHWC is the default ordering in Tensor Flow. The way TF_AllocateTensor works is different to how you are trying to use it. You should use TF_AllocateTensor in the line where you currently have the malloc() call. Then set float data = (float*)TF_TensorData(input_tensor). Then proceed with populating data array. Do not call free() on data. I hope it is more clear now.

If the data is an array populated with the numeric values of the image pixels. You answered me clearly. Can you reconfirm this?

Yes, data should be populated with numeric pixel values as you do in your code.

Try this approach.
    // (other includes)
    #include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h> 
    
    // (some other code which I'm lazy to write)
    
    // Load the image using stb_image.h
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char *image_data = stbi_load("play_accept_call1.png", &width, &height, &channels, 0);
    
    // Check if the image was loaded successfully
    if (!image_data) {
        printf("Error loading the image.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Specify input tensor dimensions (ensure these match your model's expectations)
    int ndims = 4; 
    int64_t dims[] = {1, 224, 224, 3}; 
    
    // Allocate memory to store pixel values as floats
    float *data = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * dims[1] * dims[2] * dims[3]);
    
    // Convert, normalize, and potentially resize the image data:
    if (data != NULL) {
        // Ensure your normalization and channel ordering logic is accurate!
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < channels; c++) {
                    // ... (normalize and potentially handle RGB vs. BGR)
                }
            }
        }
    
        // Create input tensor (prefer TF_NewTensor unless you need TensorFlow-managed memory)
        int ndata = sizeof(float) * dims[0] * dims[1] * dims[2] * dims[3]; 
        TF_Tensor* input_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, ndims, data, ndata, &NoOpDeallocator, 0);
    
        // ... (rest of your TenFlow inference code)
    
        // free the memory
        free(data);
    } else {
        printf("Error allocating memory.\n");
        stbi_image_free(image_data); // Still free the image data
        return 1;
    }


This is not a proper answer. What's the difference between your code and OP's code? I don't see a significant one in the diff.
